# No internet connection on Compaq 6735S laptop

Tags: broadcom, hp, compaq

I am new to Ubuntu (12.04.3). I installed the software to my laptop http://www.lapwik.com/hp-compaq_6735s for typical use (browsing, movies, music ,etc.) I am not a programmer and I can't understand what is happening with programs and drivers. I am not able to download the drivers because I don't have access to  the internet because of my network card, I think I found a driver for my network PCI, but I don't know how to use it (http://www.broadcom.com/support/802.11/linux_sta.php)

Any help?

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://askubuntu.com/a/60395/14356  - basically, remember to connect your laptop via a WIRED connection first before following the instructions as linked.

Answer (score 0):

Try install instructions:

```
mkdir hybrid_wl

cd hybrid_wl
```

download it :

if you have ubuntu 32bit

```
wget http://www.broadcom.com/docs/linux_sta/hybrid-v35-nodebug-pcoem-6_30_223_141.tar.gz
```

if you have ubuntu 64bit

```
wget http://www.broadcom.com/docs/linux_sta/hybrid-v35_64-nodebug-pcoem-6_30_223_141.tar.gz
```

extract it

```
tar xzf hybrid-v35-nodebug-pcoem-6_30_223_141.tar.gz
```

1. Build the driver as a Linux loadable kernel module (LKM):

> make clean   (optional)
>
> make

When the build completes, it will produce a wl.ko file in the top level
directory.

If your driver does not build, check to make sure you have installed the
kernel package described in the requirements above.

This driver uses cfg80211 API. Code for Wext API is present and can be built
but we have dropped support for it.
As before, the Makefile will still build the matching version for your system.

```
make API=CFG80211
```

or

```
make API=WEXT (deprecated)
```

make sure you installed :

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-generic

sudo apt-get build-dep linux
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, 
I read the instructions and i try to "build" the driver, but i can not understand what built is, what these lines of code are and where i write them, and what is this file in the driver named "make"? I dont want to waste your time so, if it is a simple way to learn how this things work please tell me about it

thank you

Comment: Open Ubuntu software center and type `bcm` in search ,
Install "Installer Package for firmware for the b34 driver" (firmware-b43-installer)

Comment: build is mean [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation)